# Testing connection to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In order to test connection to HDFS from a java program, is it sufficient enough to rely on FileSystem.get(configuration) or additional sanity checks should be done to do so?(fo ex: some file-based operations like list,copy,delete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSystem.get(Configuration) creates a DistrubutedFileSystem object, which in turn relies on a DFSClient to talk to the NameNode. Buried deep down in the source (1.0.2 is the version i'm looking through), is a call to create an RPC for the NameNode, which in turn creates a Proxy for the ClientProtocol interface.

When this proxy is created, (`org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(Class<? extends VersionedProtocol>, long, InetSocketAddress, UserGroupInformation, Configuration, SocketFactory, int)`), a call is made to ensure the server and client both talk the same 'version', so this confirmation affirms that a NameNode is running at the configured address:

```
VersionedProtocol proxy =
    (VersionedProtocol) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        protocol.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { protocol },
        new Invoker(protocol, addr, ticket, conf, factory, rpcTimeout));
long serverVersion = proxy.getProtocolVersion(protocol.getName(), 
                                              clientVersion);
if (serverVersion == clientVersion) {
  return proxy;
} else {
  throw new VersionMismatch(protocol.getName(), clientVersion, 
                            serverVersion);
}
```

Of course, whether the NameNode has sufficient datanodes running to perform some actions (such as create / open files) is not reported by this version match check.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Chris.

So, since an RPC call to the namenode is involved as a part of creating the FileSystem object, this method not throwing an IOException should be a good check to ensure that we can talk to the namenode. Correct?